# how to remove empty line with fread() in r

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I need some guidance how to read data from the file correctly - without the blank line that is placed in the first row (after the header).

The script as follows:

```
library(iotools)
library(data.table)    

#set a row qty for the dataframe
df_size<-100
#make a dataframe
n<-   data.frame(x=1:df_size,y=rnorm(1:df_size),z=rnorm(1:df_size),w=c("fgdfgd"))
n[,4]<-as.character(n[,4])
str(n)
#filename variable
file_output<-"test.csv"

#write to csv file
**fwrite_score(n,file_output)**


#read from the file saved
# option1
output<-fread(file_output, sep=";",dec=".",data.table = FALSE
              ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(output)
#option 2
output<-(fread(file_output, sep=";",,dec=".",data.table = FALSE
                ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE,))[-1,]
str(output)

#**function to write a file fast** (function is written base upon 'write.csv.raw' from 'iotools' package):
fwrite_score<-function(  df=NA
                         ,file_name=NA
                       ){

#to remove previous file
  if (file.exists(file_name)) file.remove(file_name)
  #create new file
  file(file_name, ifelse(FALSE, "ab", "wb"))
  #create connection to the new file
  zz <- file(file_name, "wb")
  #convert dataframe into binary vector
  rnames<-as.output(rbind(colnames(df),""),sep=";",nsep="\t")
  #prepare binary vector to write
  r = as.output(df, sep = ";",nsep="\t")
  #add column names to the file
  writeBin(rnames, zz)
  #add dataframe body to the file
  writeBin(r, zz)
  #close file conection
  close(zz)
  rm(zz)
  gc()
}
```

The option1 is the common 'fread' - blank line still exist.

The option2 uses the external parameter to exclude the empty line '[-1,]'.

*So **the question is** whether there is an internal parameter of `fread` to exclude the empty lines*.

The alternative solution of the issue is:

```
output<-read.csv.raw(file_output,header=TRUE,sep=";",skip=1)
str(output)
```

But my interest in `fread` option because I use it throughout my business cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fread` also has a `skip` parameter that you can use, but it is slightly different than `read.csv.raw`. So you can probably read the header first, then read the content using `skip`

Comment: @ warmoverflow.   
Thanks for the swift answer.
Well, I considered such an approach but it seems to me that the option2 is more preferrable due to its concisness. So ni any other options to make it insed 'fread'?

Comment: I read through `fread` documentation and there seems to be no other options. I am only recommending this because `fread` might be faster than `read.csv.raw`.

Comment: @ warmoverflow
Well, I have heard a lot that 'fread' is the fastest but my tests differ - 'read.csv.raw' is ~2 times as fast as 'fread' is. I have used the same dataframe but increased qty of rows up to 10 mio.

But the critical drawback of  'read.csv.raw' is so far the rigid link to "." as decimal sign (at least to me) and fewer parameters to be tuned. The 'fread' is much more flexible.

Comment: That's good to know. I'll consider `read.csv.raw` next time :)

Answer (score 1):

The argument `blank.lines.skip=TRUE` is your answer.